# How to mark vector of row sums of a matrix?

Tags: notation

We are submitting a paper documenting new statistical model. We have a matrix F<sub>i,t</sub> and a vector F<sub>i</sub>, defined like this:

[image]

Thus, the vector F<sub>i</sub> contains row sums of matrix F<sub>i,t</sub>. Since the definition of F<sub>i</sub> is basically a definition of F<sub>i,t</sub> without the recapture at time t, we thought it is nice to use the same letter for both symbols. But, the referee find it potentially confusing that we use the same letter for both vector and matrix. So:

1. Is it a frowned-upon practice to name these symbols as we did?
2. Is there some established symbology for row sums of a matrix? I thought we might use something like F<sub>i</sub><sup>*</sup> for the vector, or similar, but better would be to use something already established for row sums.

---

EDIT:

1. Thanks for the F<sub>i,*</sub> idea! But I also need to denote the whole vector of these numbers.... how would that look like? I am not sure if F<sub>1..k,*</sub> would be understandable enough.
2. I can't use lowercase **f** since I already use it for corresponding probabilities.

Comment: This question belongs at https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your notation works,  But when it costs little or nothing, you need to accept the referee's suggestion.  Many authorities use a notation like $F_{i*}$ or $F_{i,*}$ or $F_{i\odot}$ for sums over unspecified indices.

Comment: @whuber in particular I seem to recall $F_{i,\cdot}$ being used in sums of square in classical DOE books. But if the ref is dissenting and you want to use the same letter for both symbols, why not do so but use upper and lowercase,  like so: $\mathbf{f} = F\mathbf{1}$ or $f_i = \sum_{t} F_{i,t}$.

Comment: @whuber thanks! 1) You are probably right with obliging the referee, although he wrote it kindly "Consider using different letters".  2) Thanks for the F<sub>i,\*</sub> idea! But I also need to denote the whole vector of these numbers.... how would that look like? I am not sure if F<sub>1..k,\*</sub> would be understandable enough.

Comment: @JohnMadden thanks! Unfortunatelly, I can't use lowercase f since I already use it for corresponding probabilities.

Comment: It would be natural to drop the subscript and possibly make the symbol bold to denote a vector, as in $\mathbf{F}_{*} = (F_{1,*}, F_{2,*},\ldots, F_{k,*})^\prime.$

Comment: @JohnMadden, what does DOE stand for?

Comment: @Richard Design Of Experiments.  It's a standard notation for the ANOVA formulas that arise in that subject.

Comment: @whuber thank you very much!! This is the perfect solution I've been looking for, I will use this! If you add it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks again!